# Laravel push notifications are received by pusher with sync but not with redis driver

Tags: laravel, notifications

I'm trying to use Laravel's notification class to send a system notification upon an action. I'm receiving notifications when sync driver is being used, but when I switch to redis queue connection, there is no payload through pusher.

**SystemNotification.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Channels\BroadcastChannel;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\BroadcastMessage;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;

class SystemNotification extends Notification implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Queueable;

    private $event;
    private $eventData;

    public function __construct($event, $eventData) {
        $this->event = $event;
        $this->eventData = $eventData;
    }

    /**
     * Get the delivery channels for this Notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function via($notifiable) {
        return [BroadcastChannel::class];
    }

    public function toBroadcast($notifiable) {
        return (new BroadcastMessage([
            'event' => $this->event,
        ]));
    }
}
```

**.env**

```
BROADCAST_DRIVER=pusher
CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=redis
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
```

**queue.php**

```
'redis' => [
    'driver' => 'redis',
    'connection' => 'default',
    'queue' => env('REDIS_QUEUE', 'default'),
    'retry_after' => 90,
    'block_for' => null,
 ],
```

Here is the payload when I use sync driver.

[image]

My job is also being successfully processed.

[image]

I would appreciate any and all the help. Thanks!

Comment: did you manage to solve your problem?

Answer (score 3):

After config change do a `php artisan config:cache` then re run you queue workers.

Note if your are queuing to redis then you have to run your workers via `php artisan queue:listen redis` and not `php artisan queue:listen` only

If it does not work try implementing a  `ShouldBroadcastNow` interface like `class SystemNotification extends Notification implements ShouldBroadcastNow` and then recheck if its works actually it will not queue you event but execute it immediately.

Answer (score 0):

`php artisan queue:listen redis` will work for you assuming you dont have any errors

Answer (score 0):

Things to do:
Check your logs.
Check your redis database connection.
Make sure your redis dependencies are installed.
Maybe figure out what those 37 problems are.

Try `php artisan config:cache`

Try `php artisan queue:listen redis`

I expected

```
public function via($notifiable) {
    return [BroadcastChannel::class];
}
```

to be

```
public function via($notifiable) {
    return ['broadcast'];
}
```

Other than this I couldn't find anything "off" with your code.

The documentation for redis queues can be found here:
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queues#driver-prerequisites